# Create a multi-stack (e.g., 12 color) tiff image in python for ImageJ

Tags: python, numpy, tiff, scikit-image, imagej

I have an array with dimension (5000, 5000, 12) representing X, Y and color. It is already `dtype=uint16`.

I would like to create a tiff stack from this array so I can load it in ImageJ. My approach so far:

```
skimage.io.imsave(
   'Top4cores.tif', full_small_image,
    bigtiff=True, imagej=True, resolution=(1, 1),
    metadata={'spacing': 1, 'unit': 'um', 'axes': 'XYC'},photometric='minisblack')
```

Unfortunately, this creates an image with:

```
SizeC = 5000
SizeT = 1
SizeX = 18
SizeY = 5000
SizeZ = 1
```

How can I make sure my image has the correct coordinates? Do I have to export individual images and stack them afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`skimage.io.imsave` uses [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) under the hood. Recent versions raise `builtins.ValueError: ImageJ hyperstack axes must be in TZCYXS order`. To fix this error, update tifffile, reverse the dimensions of your array, and use `axes='CYX'`:

```
tifffile.imwrite(
    'Top4cores.tif',
    full_small_image.transpose(),
    imagej=True,
    resolution=(1, 1),
    photometric='minisblack',
    metadata={'spacing': 1, 'unit': 'um', 'axes': 'CYX'}
)
```